# Reading a line into a char array in C

Tags: c

I'm trying to read a file in C which has a list of IP addresses in the following form.

```
1 121.20.35.8 5634
2 179.105.43.24 2345
3 122.45.36.102 5096
4 28.105.63.41 8081
5 128.20.6.250 1864
```

I'm trying to write the IP Address into the relevant index. Though the relevant index might not be in order. As in, a file of this type is quite possible.

```
 3 122.45.36.102 5096
 1 121.20.35.8 5634
 4 28.105.63.41 8081
 2 179.105.43.24 2345
 5 128.20.6.250 1864
```

I've allocated an array to hold the addresses

```
    char** servers = malloc(sizeof(char*)*10);
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
    {
        servers[i] = malloc(sizeof(char)*(MAX_IP + 1));
    }
```

And reading the file using this code. MAX_IP here is the strlen of 255.255.255.255

```
   static const char filename[] = "file.txt";
   FILE *file = fopen ( filename, "r" );
   char line [MAX_IP + 10];
   while ( fgets ( line, sizeof line, file ) != NULL ) /* read a line */
    {
       //split the line into index and IP address and store the IP   address in the relevant index
    }
      fclose ( file );
```

So now I want to read the file in a way split the line into index and IP address and store the IP   address in the relevant index. Need a little help as to the most efficient way to go about it.

Comment: You're using variable `topology`. Is that a typo?  Should it be `servers[I]` etc?

Comment: Yup, it's a typo, corrected.

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: @JonathonReinhart updated.

Comment: What do you mean by "relevant index"?

Comment: Try `int index = atoi(strtok(line, " ")) - 1; strcpy(servers[index], strtok(NULL, " "));`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
while ( fgets ( line, sizeof line, file ) != NULL )
{ int idx, port; char ip[MAX_IP + 1];
  sscanf(line, " %d %s %d", &idx, ip, &port);
  strncpy(servers[idx-1], ip, MAX_IP + 1);
}
```

But of course, if you are not sure about the correctness of your input file, you should add error checking.

EDIT: Since you are asking for "efficient way", you can do the reading in one step, instead of reading a line and then parsing it. You can do this as well:

```
int idx, port; char ip[MAX_IP + 1];
while (3 == fscanf(file, " %d %s %d", &idx, ip, &port))
   memcpy(servers[idx-1], ip, MAX_IP + 1);
```

Notice that memcpy is faster than strcpy, unless the source string is much smaller than the buffer's size, which is rarely the case with ip addesses...

Comment: Is it your coding convention to have a statement on the `while` loop brace line?

Comment: @FiddlingBits yes, indeed I have taken the habit to compress my code as much as possible in the vertical direction, because I am fed up with scrolling the screen up and down to read my code...While in fact, most screens are wide. I know I am almost alone to do this, but still, I think it is readable and does not suffer anything.